# A word for high level officials in the government

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good word for high level officials in the government? The officials I have in mind are in the upper echelon in the government hierarchy and can wield broad power.  What I want to say is: (this group of officials) is the target of corruption inquiry.

**Edit**: To clarify, I’m looking for a word for a group (or a class) of high level state officials (vs low level bureaucrats) in a non-democratic, authoritarian government where systemic corruption is rampant. These officials usually enjoy special privileges and do not need to be accountable to the public. I might have hastily generalized to “all” high level government officials; however in countries where officials are not necessarily democratically elected and corruption is widespread, when you hold high office, you are thought of as a member of (this) group.

Comment: Do you mean Civil Servants (the back-room departmental guys who are what "officials" usually refers to), or elected representatives? I *suspect* what you want is "Cabinet" but currently it's not clear which group you're referring to.

Comment: Which government?  Which heirarchy?

Comment: You could be referring to either *elected officials/office-holders* (e.g. a cabinet or senior ministers) or *unelected/appointed* (or *non-elected*) *officials* (i.e. senior civil servants). As Andrew Leach says, it's not apparent who you mean.

Comment: Andrew,Oldcat,Erik:Sorry for not making it clearer. I’m looking for a word for a group (or a class) of high level state officials (vs low level bureaucrats) in a non-democratic, authoritarian government where systemic corruption is rampant. These officials usually enjoy special privileges and do not need to be accountable to the public. 
I might have hastily generalized to “all” high level government officials; however in countries where officials are not necessarily democratically elected and corruption is widespread, when you hold high office, you are thought of as a member of (this) group.

Comment: I think it depends on which government you are describing because different governments use different terms to describe their civil servants. For example, _ministry officials_ could be what you want, but that only works for governments that organize themselves into what they call _ministries_. The same with _agency heads_,  _commissioners_, and so on.

Comment: **Mucky mucks** is a good, if somewhat insulting  way to indicate such officials. **Muckety mucks** is also used: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muckety%E2%80%93muck

Answer (score 4):

A so-called [mandarin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mandarin) was a high-ranking official of imperial China who qualified by study and academic excellence rather than inheritance or influence.

The term has been adopted by the English-speaking world to describe powerful high-ranking bureaucrats in any administration, particulary ones who are thought to wield shadowy and unaccountable power.

This seems like the sort of word you are thinking about.

Comment: I love this use of the word, used it all the time in my undergrad.  Always made me hungry for sweet citrus fruit.

Comment: @John Oooh Juicy!!!

Comment: literally came here to say this.

Answer (score 3):

**Oligarch**

> a person who belongs to a small group of people who govern or control a country, business, etc. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oligarch).

Other possibilities are

- *Bureaucrat* for any professional government worker; but generally is used for people lower in the pecking order.
- *Apparatchik* is largely synonymous with *Bureaucrat*, but with more negative connotations.

Comment: "Oligarch" is really not appropriate. Apart from direct democracies, everywhere in the world actual power is held by a few. It doesn't make these States oligarchies, and using the word "oligarch" in this context is really badly connoted. Would you call the president of the US an "oligarch", for example? They're the highest level official in the government, but the word "oligarch" doesn't apply...

Comment: @Najib Technically, yes I would. *Oligarch* has been much used in the last decade with a negative connotation, leading to your current view. Time will tell whether the meaning of this word solidifies with that negative meaning or not. Local political views can have an effect here also, leading to localised meanings.

Answer (score 1):

In such governments, emotional closeness to the dictator/tyrant is very important, not only for the continued ability to wield power, but also for one's own personal survival. In such cases, you could stress this relation, by using language like *cadre* or *inner circle*. Perhaps *high council*?

Answer (score 1):

The first word that occurred to me was **apparatchik**, but then I happened upon **nomenklatura**.

From Wikipedia:

> [**Apparatchik**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparatchik):
>   (Russian: аппара́тчик [ɐpɐˈratɕɪk]) A Russian
>   colloquial term for a full-time, professional functionary of the Communist Party or
>   government "apparat" (apparatus) that held any position of
>   bureaucratic or political responsibility, with the exception of the
>   higher ranks of management called "**Nomenklatura**".
>
> [**Nomenklatura**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenklatura): (Russian: номенклату́ра; IPA: [nəmʲɪnklɐˈturə]; Latin:
>   nomenclatura) A category of people within the Soviet Union and
>   other Eastern Bloc countries who held various key administrative
>   positions in the bureaucracy running all spheres of those countries'
>   activity: government, industry, agriculture, education, etc., whose
>   positions were granted only with approval by the communist party of
>   each country or region.

As per your comment:

> "I’m looking for a word for a group (or a class) of high level state
>   officials (vs low level bureaucrats) in a non-democratic,
>   authoritarian government where systemic corruption is rampant. These
>   officials usually enjoy special privileges and do not need to be
>   accountable to the public."

It would seem that the word you are looking for is **nomenklatura**.

Answer (score 0):

Techocrats--a general term for unelected specialists in government who often hold high or even ministerial positions. The EU government in Brussels has regiments of these 'specialists'. The term is used to describe specialists in certain areas of government , but lately it's used to describe high-level officials generally.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem with your question is that you seem to want a name broad enough to encompass members whose position dictates that they would be a member, but also that they could all be lumped into a comprehensive investigation or inquiry.

So, maybe the entire president's *cabinet* could be under inquiry. However, the Supreme Court justices and Senate leader are often higher (read powerful) positions than some, but not all of the cabinet positions. The positions are so disparate, it's difficult to imagine a circumstance where they'd all be under inquiry. **In my mind most democratic governments are actually constructed to be at odds at the highest levels.**

If, regardless of their branch of government, they might be still be under suspicion by association (e.g. rank), then maybe you could just say *leadership* positions.

> The leadership positions across most or all government institutions were under suspicion.

Maybe:

> The controlling interests, in veritably all facets of government, were suspected of widespread collusion with the President's inner circle.

Answer (score 0):

> ***[the powers that be](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/powers-that-be)*** [the Cambridge English Dictionary]:
>
>   important people who have authority over others:
>   *It’s up to the powers that be to decide what should be done next.*
>
> ***[MFWIC](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=MFWIC)*** [the Urban Dictionary]:
>
>   Off-color slang:

>   Mother Fucker What’s In Charge

Answer (score -1):

I have often seen the term *mandarin* used in the media for this exact purpose.

From the [online Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mandarin):

> **mandarin:** A powerful official or senior bureaucrat, especially one perceived as reactionary and secretive.

Comment: Please consider either expanding your answer or deleting it. Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the phrases *high-ranking* government officials or *high level* government officials.